# XmlHttpRequest Exception 101 on PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Trying to automatize a task but phantomjs can't "open" [this](https://notalegal.sefin.ro.gov.br/contribuinte/form.jsp?sys=NPJ&formID=%7BC90B91CE-E9C3-46B2-8FED-75B7B219A3AD%7D&scrolling=yes) url correctly.

The app give a 101 error.

The errors is reproducible with this script

```
var page = new WebPage();

page.open(phantom.args[0], function(status){
  console.log(status);
  page.render(phantom.args[1]);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

and running the command `phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes script.js https://notalegal.sefin.ro.gov.br/contribuinte/form.jsp\?sys\=NPJ\&formID\=\{C90B91CE-E9C3-46B2-8FED-75B7B219A3AD\}\&scrolling\=yes ~/page.png`

I've tested with phantomjs 1.4 and 1.6

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clue why it doesn't work, but I found a (sort of) workaround: Use URL shorteners :)

When I do `phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes script.js http://tinyurl.com/cu2orzg page.png`, it doesn't give any errors. It renders the exact same thing (an image saying Illegal Operation) as your link does. Maybe your link is expired or something...

Comment: I've tested with zombie.js and seens that the problem is that a script on the page try to use document.captureEvents and die because of this.